# Is there a way to load image data directly from main folder into training and validation generator instead of creating seperate same folders again?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm working on a multiple class classification model it has more than 4000 classes means 4000 folders for each class which occupies space around 30GB, to train the classification model I'm copy-pasting images into train and validation folders for each class in order to be in a classification folder structure which will take another 30GB of space and lots of time to read data.
Im using ImageDataGenerator API from keras to load data and feeding to the model for training as below

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(Training_DIR, batch_size= batch_size, class_mode='categorical',target_size=(img_height,img_width)

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(VALIDATION_DIR, batch_size= batch_size, class_mode='categorical',target_size=(img_height,img_width)
```

then passing these generator to model.fit_generator function as below

```
model.fit_generator(train,generator,validation_data=validation_generator)
```

is there a  better way to load data in high speed  directly from main folder containing subfolders with classes instead of creating new directories and copying images to it which will take twice disk size. I haven't dealt with these kind of large datasets which is taking up all my drive spaces.

Update:
I tried the solution given by @GerryP but I ended up getting error as below

> Epoch 1/50
> 2021-09-06 17:22:12.576079: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:369] Loaded cuDNN version
> 8101
> 2021-09-06 17:22:13.251294: W
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:272] Allocator
> (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.19GiB with
> freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but
> may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were
> available.
> 2021-09-06 17:22:16.096112: E
> tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1010] failed to
> synchronize the stop event: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_TIMEOUT: the launch
> timed out and was terminated
> 2021-09-06 17:22:16.096299: E
> tensorflow/stream_executor/gpu/gpu_timer.cc:55] Internal: Error
> destroying CUDA event: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_TIMEOUT: the launch timed out
> and was terminated
> 2021-09-06 17:22:16.097126: E
> tensorflow/stream_executor/gpu/gpu_timer.cc:60] Internal: Error
> destroying CUDA event: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_TIMEOUT: the launch timed out
> and was terminated
> 2021-09-06 17:22:16.097682: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:732] failed to allocate
> 8B (8 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_TIMEOUT: the launch timed
> out and was terminated
> 2021-09-06 17:22:16.097935: E
> tensorflow/stream_executor/stream.cc:4508] Internal: Failed to enqueue
> async memset operation: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_TIMEOUT: the launch timed
> out and was terminated
> 2021-09-06 17:22:16.098312: W tensorflow/core/kernels/gpu_utils.cc:69]
> Failed to check cudnn convolutions for out-of-bounds reads and writes
> with an error message: 'Failed to load in-memory CUBIN:
> CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_TIMEOUT: the launch timed out and was terminated';
> skipping this check. This only means that we won't check cudnn for
> out-of-bounds reads and writes. This message will only be printed
> once.
> 2021-09-06 17:22:16.098676: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:732] failed to allocate
> 8B (8 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_TIMEOUT: the launch timed
> out and was terminated
> 2021-09-06 17:22:16.099006: E
> tensorflow/stream_executor/stream.cc:4508] Internal: Failed to enqueue
> async memset operation: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_TIMEOUT: the launch timed
> out and was terminated
> 2021-09-06 17:22:16.099369: F
> tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:216] Check failed: status
> == CUDNN_STATUS_SUCCESS (7 vs. 0)Failed to set cuDNN stream.

Comment: Does each of the 4000 classes occupy 30GB, or all the data is 30GB? How much RAM does your machine have? Do you use GPU to train the net? Do you use multiple GPUs? In other words, what is the bottleneck in your training? The optimal solution heavily depends on these factors.

Comment: all data together has 30GB , I've ram of 64GB with swap memory , yes I'm using single GPU for training , bottleneck is when it create new folders and images it'lll fillup the memory and stops training saying your disk is full

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Even though the answer from @[Gerry P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10798917/gerry-p) is IMO correct and answers what OP asked for. Here is another answer motivated by the discussion in the comments which tries to prevent unnecessary bottleneck caused by I/O operations during training while using `.flow_from_directory()` or `.flow_from_dataframe()`.*

**Disclaimer: this solution works only if all the images are of the same shape.**

I am suggesting to use the `.flow()` method of the `ImageDataGenerator` in combination with `numpy.memmap`. You can create one memmap for each subset of data, i.e. `train`, `validation`, and `test` sets. I have created a [Google Colab notebook](https://gist.github.com/paloha/b3262376debaf18fd33b5961b3a51ebf) in which I compare the methods using the MNIST dataset. Here is the most important code from that notebook:

```
# Initiating a memmap on drive with specified shape and dtype
mmap = np.memmap('mnist.mmap', dtype='uint8', mode='w+', shape=(x_test.shape))

# Filling the memmap with data
# If hard disk space is a problem, we can delete the source image files on the go
for i, fpath in enumerate(fpaths):
    mmap[i][:] = np.expand_dims(imread(fpath)[:], -1)
    # deleting the file if desired
    # os.remove(fpath)

# Loading the memmap from disk (does not load all the data to RAM), shape must be specified
mmap = np.memmap('mnist.mmap', dtype='uint8', mode='r', shape=(x_test.shape))

DataGen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
gen = DataGen.flow(mmap, y=None, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, seed=10)
```

Bellow are the results of measuring how much time it took to generate 2 epochs from the MNIST testing set (10k grayscale images 28x28).

| Method | Source | Batch size | Time* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `.flow()` | np.array | 1 | 584 ms |
|  |  | 8 | 293 ms |
|  |  | 32 | 285 ms |
|  |  | 256 | 280 ms |
| `.flow()` | memmap | 1 | 574 ms |
|  |  | 8 | 296 ms |
|  |  | 32 | 278 ms |
|  |  | 256 | 274 ms |
| `flow_from_directory()` | files | 1 | 3.96 s |
|  |  | 8 | 3.50 s |
|  |  | 32 | 3.39 s |
|  |  | 256 | 3.41 s |
| `flow_from_dataframe()` | files | 1 | 3.97 s |
|  |  | 8 | 3.50 s |
|  |  | 32 | 3.41 s |
|  |  | 256 | 3.39 s |

- time to generate 2 epochs (i.e. 2x the whole testing set)

Maybe [this blog](https://medium.com/swlh/dump-keras-imagedatagenerator-start-using-tensorflow-tf-data-part-1-a30330bdbca9) which suggest to use `tf.data` instead of the aforementioned `ImageDataGenerator` might be interesting for the readers of this question. Though, I have not tested it myself.

Comment: this is great, I'll try this np.array method and I'll share the results . Thanks for this brief solution.

Comment: The difference between using the np.array and memmap is that with np.array, you need to load the whole dataset into RAM. With memmap you only load one batch in RAM at a time.

Comment: This is my experience too. Making flow_from_dataframe() useless!

Answer (score 1):

You can leave all your images in a single directory train_data_dir. Then you can use the code below to partition the data into a train set, a validation set and a test set. The code creates 3 data frames, train_df, test_df, and valid_df. It then creates 3 generators train_gen, test_gen and valid_gen. You can then use train_gen and valid_gen in modl.fit. Use test_gen in model,evaluate or model.predict.

```
def preprocess (sdir, trsplit, vsplit, random_seed):
    filepaths=[]
    labels=[]    
    classlist=os.listdir(sdir)
    for klass in classlist:
        classpath=os.path.join(sdir,klass)
        flist=os.listdir(classpath)
        for f in flist:
            fpath=os.path.join(classpath,f)
            filepaths.append(fpath)
            labels.append(klass)
    Fseries=pd.Series(filepaths, name='filepaths')
    Lseries=pd.Series(labels, name='labels')
    df=pd.concat([Fseries, Lseries], axis=1)       
    # split df into train_df and test_df 
    dsplit=vsplit/(1-trsplit)
    strat=df['labels']    
    train_df, dummy_df=train_test_split(df, train_size=trsplit, shuffle=True, random_state=random_seed, stratify=strat)
    strat=dummy_df['labels']
    valid_df, test_df=train_test_split(dummy_df, train_size=dsplit, shuffle=True, random_state=random_seed, stratify=strat)
    print('train_df length: ', len(train_df), '  test_df length: ',len(test_df), '  valid_df length: ', len(valid_df))
    print(list(train_df['labels'].value_counts())) # shows number of samples in each class to evaluate balance
    return train_df, test_df, valid_df
sdir=train_data_dir
train_df, test_df, valid_df= preprocess(sdir, .8,.1, 123)
# now create the 3 generators
batch_size=32 # set desired batch size
img_size=(img_height, img_width)
# determine test_batch_size and test_steps so test_batch_size X test_steps= no of test samples
#this insures you evaluate all test samples exactly one time
length=len(test_df)
test_batch_size=sorted([int(length/n) for n in range(1,length+1) if length % n ==0 and length/n<=80],reverse=True)[0]  
test_steps=int(length/test_batch_size)
trgen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, shear_range=0.2, 
                            zoom_range=0.2,horizontal_flip=True)
tvgen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_gen=trgen.flow_from_dataframe( train_df, x_col='filepaths', y_col='labels', target_size=img_size, class_mode='categorical',
                                    color_mode='rgb', shuffle=True, 
                                    batch_size=batch_size)
test_gen=tvgen.flow_from_dataframe( test_df, x_col='filepaths', y_col='labels', target_size=img_size, class_mode='categorical',
                                    color_mode='rgb', shuffle=False, 
                                     batch_size=test_batch_size)

valid_gen=tvgen.flow_from_dataframe( valid_df, x_col='filepaths', y_col='labels', target_size=img_size, class_mode='categorical',
                                    color_mode='rgb', shuffle=True, 
                                    batch_size=batch_size)
classes=list(train_gen.class_indices.keys())
class_count=len(classes)
# then train your model
history=model.fit(x=train_gen,  epochs=epochs, verbose=1,  
                validation_data=valid_gen,
                validation_steps=None,  shuffle=True,  initial_epoch=0)
```

Comment: hey thanks for the suggestion I'll try this out, could you explain how would it save dataframe? if I've data more than ram size would it stop training?

Comment: You have to have enough memory to hold the dataframes. This should not be a problem since the dataframes do not contain any images, it just contains the path to the image files. Images will be loaded in batches as set by batch_size. Images are what consumes a lot of memory but since they are loaded in batches this prevents OOM error. If you do get an OOM error, reduce the batch size.

Comment: Yes, this is a solution, and it does what OP asked for. But it will severly slow down the training due to lots of I/O operations. I.e. the data generator has to open each image every time it needs to be passed through the network. I would approach this with memory maps. I would create one big numpy.memmap which would hold all the images, along with a meta file holding e.g. the original filenames. I would then use the memmap in my data generator. Getting an image from a memmap on the disk is orders of magnitude faster than opening an image file.

Comment: @GerryP thanks I'll share the result of this approach

Comment: @Paloha hey thanks for this new approach , I'll try this out, can you give me an example how to implement this method for my use case?

Comment: I can but when I am at my computer. Hard to make an example from a phone.

Comment: it's ok , do it when you get time

Comment: @GerryP I tried your approach I ended up getting above error , please check the question I tested on sample of length train 32000 val 4000 test 4000 , is this OOM issue? my GPU has 8GB memory

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? Make the same image data generator with a validation split argument. and then initilize Flow from directory data generator with different subsets, i.e subset='training', subset='validation'. You can see the ex

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.2) # set validation split

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='training') # set as training data

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir, # same directory as training data
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='validation') # set as validation data

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = train_generator.samples // batch_size,
    validation_data = validation_generator, 
    validation_steps = validation_generator.samples // batch_size,
    epochs = nb_epochs)
```

Comment: No I haven't tried this, will this save data again or manipulate main directory files?

Comment: I used this approach I ended up getting val_loss is not available key error, does this has to be trained on larger sample only?

Comment: No! I Kindlly copy paste the error So that I can help you out

Comment: I did please check the question

Comment: did you check the edited question , what's causing error in checkpoint?

Comment: change weights.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.h5 to weights.{epoch:02d}-{validation_loss:.2f}.h5.. I think this may be a problem

Comment: I changed and got the same error as KeyError: 'validation_loss'

Comment: than just use this weights.{epoch:02d}.h5